# How to get value from mysql, back to front end and used in a url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am having trouble getting all the information I need back from a PHP script in response to an AJAX request made from a web page.

I have a front-end form:

```
<form method="post" id="register-form">
    <input class="form-control" id="firstname" name="first name" placeholder="Fornavn" type="text" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="btn-save" id="btn-submit">
        Next page &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>  
    </button>
```

which uses AJAX to post the data:

```
function submitForm(){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        async: false, // NEW
        url  : 'register.php',
        data : $("#register-form").serialize(),
        dataType: 'json', 
        success :  function(data){
            if ( data.status==='success' ) {
                $("#btn-submit").html('<span class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></span> &nbsp; Saving  ...');
                $('#btn-submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $(".reg-form").fadeOut(500);
                $(".ChooseProductForm").fadeIn(500);
            }

        });
        return false;
    }
```

which after a successful response ends up displaying two link buttons:

```
<a href="goHome.php?userID=XX" class="btn btn-buy-now" role="button">Go home</a>
<a href="goAway.php?userID=XX" class="btn btn-buy-now" role="button">Go Away</a>
```

In the link `href` values, XX are placeholder charactersfor a `$LastInsertedID` value generated in PHP.

My PHP file:

```
<?php
$response = array();
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $user_firstname         = trim_inputs($_POST['firstname']);
    $user_joining_date      = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $response['status'] = 'success';
    $SaveData = "INSERT INTO Users (firstname, joined)
                VALUES ('".$user_firstname."', '".$user_joining_date."' )";

    if (mysqli_query($link, $SaveData)) {
        $LastInsertedID = mysqli_insert_id($link);
    } else {
        $response['status'] = 'error';
        //echo "Error: " . $SaveData . "<br>" . mysqli_error($link);
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Everything works just like it should, but can't understand how to get the `$LastInsertedID` value back to front-end to those two buttons.

I know there is an array for $response, but how to get the value back.
Also displaying a message like:

```
$response['message'] = 'Welcome user';
```

I can get out, but if I then add URL or < a href... tag into that message, nothing would be displayed.

Thanks for reading this question, hopefully it is understandable  and maybe someone could help out :-)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are the two buttons generated? You are open to SQL injections with this as well.

Comment: Put the id in your response. Inside your success callback (inside submitForm function) grab the id from the response and you have two options: 1.) save it in a cookie, and then on the next page read that cookie. 2.) put the id in the url and then when next page loads, grab that id from the url

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for this, i will rewrite the script!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the new ID back:

```
if (mysqli_query($link, $SaveData)) {
    $LastInsertedID = mysqli_insert_id($link);
    $response['userId'] = $LastInsertedID;
} else {
    $response['status'] = 'error';
}
```

Use that ID:

```
success :  function(data)
{ 
    if ( data.status==='success' ) {
        $("#btn-submit").html('<span class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></span> &nbsp; Saving  ...');
        $('#btn-submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $(".reg-form").fadeOut(500);
        $(".ChooseProductForm").fadeIn(500);
        $("#id-of-go-away-button").attr("href", "goAway.php?userId=" + data.userId);
        $("#id-of-go-home-button").attr("href", "goHome.php?userId=" + data.userId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. Now i understood what i should do!

Answer (score 1):

Small changes to the javascript. I moved the code to display the spinner and tell the user you are saving to before the ajax call.
Then I added code to get the new ID from the data returned by the ajax call, and a mock up of putting into a field.

**Javascript Code:**

```
function submitForm(){
    $("#btn-submit").html('<span class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></span> &nbsp; Saving...');
    $('#btn-submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $.ajax(
        {
            type : 'POST',
            async: false, // NEW
            url  : 'register.php',
            data : $("#register-form").serialize(),
            dataType: 'json', 
            success :  function(data) { 
                if ( data.status==='success' ) {
                    $("#btn-submit").html('Saved.');
                    $(".reg-form").fadeOut(500);
                    $(".ChooseProductForm").fadeIn(500);
                    var new_id = data.new_id;
                    $("#field to hold the new id").val(new_id);
                }
            }
        }
    );
    return false;
}
```

On the server, we just need to add the new id to the data returned to the caller.

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
    $response = array();
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $user_firstname = trim_inputs($_POST['firstname']);
        $user_joining_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $response['status'] = 'success';
        $response['error_message'] = "";
        $SaveData = "INSERT INTO Users (firstname, joined) VALUES ('".$user_firstname."', '".$user_joining_date."' )";

        if (mysqli_query($link, $SaveData)) {
            $LastInsertedID = mysqli_insert_id($link);
            $response['new_id'] = $LastInsertedID;
            $response['message'] = "Welcome new user!";
        } else {
            $response['status'] = 'error';
            $response['error_message'] = $SaveData . "<br>" . mysqli_error($link);
        }
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```